# What is the missing number from this pattern?

Tags: arithmetic

I tried every combination I could think of, but I just can't figure out this pattern.
A.21  B.9  C.0  D.2
[image]

Comment: If no context is given, such exercises are just ill-posed. We can find a "reasonable guess" , but the author can always have something different in mind.

Comment: It seems that the number in the middle is half of the sum of the four numbers outside the square.For example $11=(3+7+9+3)/2$.

Comment: As @Crostul says, I think the answer is then $(-2)$ , but I really didn't like this question.

Answer (score 0):

Big hint: $$\frac{2+2+3+3}{2}=5.$$

This pattern holds for the other two, see if you can calculate the blank.